# Restore work space after reboot?

Tags: windows-7, reboot

Is there a way to reboot windows 7 with the option of saving the current working session and restoring it after reboot?

So after reboot, my browser is automatically launched without losing any tabs, Word automatically brings me up to the current doc I am working on, etc.

Comment: Do you mean like [Hibernation](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/Sleep-and-hibernation-frequently-asked-questions), or an actual reboot?

Comment: Any modern laptop/desktop should support either "Hibernate" of "Suspend" which will keep your apps open when you restore the session.

Comment: Most browsers will support booting up with a pre-determined set of pages loaded, if that suits your needs.

Comment: I mean reboot, go to shutdown->restart

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this:  http://cachemywork.codeplex.com/ - "Cache My Work: reopen your Apps after reboot":

> CacheMyWork is a handy utility that enables you to reboot Windows
>   without losing your place in your work. It builds a checklist of
>   currently open applications, and will restart the apps you've selected
>   the next time you logon to the computer.  Cache My Work is great for
>   occasions when you need to unexpectedly reboot...

Answer (score 1):

Hibernation should do this for you (and Microsoft has implemented it into all versions of Windows since Windows 2000.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernation doesn't reboot the machine though.  If you need to reboot the machine after hotfixes get applied, personally I would still like to have my open applications reopen upon reboot.  I use hibernation all the time instead of powering off my machine, but reboots are inevitable.  You can try a product called Twinsplay Professional.

Comment: Twinsplay Professional is a very expensive product to be used just for a session saving.